# AlarmManager scheduling

Tags: android

I'm  trying to schedule my alarm manager to fire up an intent every hour in a day. 
this is what I do , and it doesnt work properly.

code:

```
 new code after edit:


          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY , 22); //22:00 of every evening
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE , 0); //initiate minute time
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND , 0);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, randomMinutes); //adding mintues so we get random time btw 22:00-07:00
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); //switching to the next day.



    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

randomMinutesis some number from 0 to 600

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the third parameter is supposed to be your period, and you have `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, meaning the alarm will go off every random-number-of-milliseconds-since-the-phone-was-started.

If you want a 60-minute period, use `3600000` for your third parameter.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a similar question. I currently have an alarm in my app that runs once a day, just to check on a given server and ready.
But it runs only once a day at the time the application created the instance of alarm. That is, if the application is open to the first 3 PM every day following the application will "alarm" at 3 PM.
What I want is that independende the time the application was run the first time, the alarm is executed every time the 10 AM, for example.
How can I do this?

Comment: @WalterBarreiroNeto: Use `java.util.Calendar` to construct the time of the first event, use an `RTC`-flavored alarm, and use 24-hours-in-milliseconds for the period.